# ArcGIS 10 Split string from OSM data

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, attribute-table, python-parser, string

maybe you can help

I have a string:

"width"=>"6","name:be"=>"Калінавы завулак","name:ru"=>"Калиновый переулок","surface"=>"asphalt","int_name"=>"Kalinavy zavulak","maxspeed"=>"40"

necessary as a distinct attribute : **Kalinavy zavulak**

my test:

Split( [Your_Field_Name] , "int_name"=>",)(1)

[image]

But something goes wrong

Comment: What goes wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument of the split function is expecting a string value surrounded by "" or ''.  You have three double quotes.  Try surrounding the string with single quotes:

```
!other_tags!.split('"int_name"=>"')[1]
```

To remove the last bit of text, run this statement after running the one noted above:

```
!other_tags!.split(',')[0].replace('"','')
```

Comment: Thank you for just one more                                                              problem,                                                                                                    Kalinavy zavulak","maxspeed"=>"40"                                      ","maxspeed"=>"40" - not needet

Comment: @ru-ubuntu, what is your question?

Comment: Now everything apart from "int_name "=>" and I need just to name -  Kalinavy zavulak

Comment: @ru-ubuntu, updated my answer